# Solving separable equations with dy/dx on both sides?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm unsure on how to even start with this equation:
$y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=1+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$

I thought it would be possible to cancel out but the answer was different. Could someone please provide a hint on how to start this equation? I thought about moving the $-x\frac{dy}{dx}$ over to the RHS and then group it under the common variable $\frac{dy}{dx}$ but the question was under the 'separable differential' section in my textbook so I don't think it's the correct method.

Comment: Does thee text mean $\frac{dy}{f(y)}=\frac{dx}{g(x)}$?  If so you have $\frac{dy}{y-1}=\frac{dx}{x+x^2}$.

Comment: I don't think so because the answer is $y-1=\frac{x}{x+1}$, which your method didn't give (assuming I did the correct calculations) at y=3/2 and x=1

Comment: It looks like I was right and someone worked it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(x + x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} = y - 1$$
By *separation of variables*,
$$\int \frac{dy}{y-1} = \int\frac{dx}{x+x^2}$$
$$\log (y-1)  = \log x - \log (x+1) + \text{constant}$$
$$y - 1 = \frac{Cx}{x+1}$$
$$y = \frac{Cx + x + 1}{x+1}$$

---

As you have mentioned in the comments, you wish to use $x = 1$ and $y = \frac32$ as the initial values, to find $C$. We have $\frac32 = \frac{C+2}{2}$, which gives $C = 1$. The solution is therefore $$y = \frac{2x+1}{x+1}$$
which is the same as $y -1 = \frac{x}{x+1}$ as you have stated.

Comment: Can you please explain the first step? I don't understand why the dy/dx on the RHS is gone?

Comment: How you reach from
$$\int \frac{dy}{y-1} = \int\frac{dx}{x+x^2}$$ to
$$\log (y-1)  = \log x - \log (x+1) + \text{constant}$$

Comment: how you got from $y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=1+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$ to $(x+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx} = y-1$

Comment: I literally just shifted terms left and right across the equality sign. Can you see it? @Mathhurtsmybrain

Comment: @MiladDastanZand These are very standard integrals, and it is expected that you know how to deal with them before studying ordinary differential equations. Anyway, you can write $\frac{1}{x+x^2} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}$ and proceed.

Comment: Oh, yeah that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @delta-divine You are right
I was away from math for a while. I just walk here to remember things again. Thanks for the explanation. I take an upvote to your answer.

Comment: But then after you put them into logs: $ln(y-1)=ln(\frac{x}{x-1})+C$ how did you get rid of the logs? and moved the C into the numerator?

Comment: If $\log A = \log B$, then $A = B$. The constant can be absorbed inside the logarithm, since you can write it as $\log C$ for some $C > 0$. @Mathhurtsmybrain

Answer (score 0):

$$y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=1+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\dfrac {y-xy'}{x^2}=\dfrac 1{x^2}+y'$$
$$-\left (\dfrac y{x} \right)'=\dfrac 1{x^2}+y'$$
Integrate.
$$\dfrac y{x}=\dfrac 1{x}-y+C_1$$
$$y(x)=\dfrac {Cx+1}{x+1}$$